# Store MD5 hash in SQLITE3 database in python

Tags: python, hash, sqlite

Currently my database stores the 'password' as text, but this says it does not work as shown below (The password is also converted into MD5 hash):

Password 'function':

```
user_in = input("Please enter a password next to this text: \n")
Password = hashlib.md5()
Password.update(user_in.encode("utf-8"))
```

Error message:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

What I want to know is how I store the hash in a database in SQLITE3

Edit:

```
cursor=db.cursor()   
sql="insert into Accounts (Username, Password) values(?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql, (Username, Password))                      
db.commit()
```

Edit 2:

```
user_in = input("Please enter a password next to this text: \n")
Password = hashlib.md5()
Password.update(user_in.encode("utf-8"))
Password.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Are you getting the error when running the python function, or when actually submitting it to the SQLServer?

Comment: @Polymer Hi again. I am getting the error after I have input the username and password, so when it's being submitted to the SQL server

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to submit it to the server, please? Also on your server, what type do you have your password set as?

Comment: @Polymer It is set as text. I will add the code above.

Comment: Are you using password.hexdigest() for the Password variable?

Comment: @Polymer Yes I am

Comment: @Polymer I will add the code that hashes the password

Comment: Could you try and cast the arguments. Ie `cursor.execute(sql, (str(Username), str(Password)))`

Comment: @Polymer Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly. Mind putting that into a separate answer so I can choose it?

Comment: Done, would be better practice to cast the strings outside of the function by the way. Just do Username = str(Username)/password and you should be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure arguments for cursor.execute functions are actually strings and you'll be golden! :)

```
cursor.execute(sql, (str(Username), str(Password)))
```

This is done by casting them during the argument pass

Comment: Hey Polymer, I know this kinda unrelated but I wanted to ask a question.  If I wanted to add a sign in function, how would I check that the username and password were related?

Comment: I am aware I would have to change the user's guess to MD5 as well to correspond to the one in the database but how would I look to make sure that it is that user's password specifically.

Comment: And how would I see if Username was in the database then see if the password is correct

Comment: Eg. If username IN Accounts.db (Obviously not correct syntax)

Comment: Basically, you need to use the username provided, go to your database and get the hashed password. Then, you hash the password they entered with the same md5 and compare it to the one in the database. If both hashings are the same, let them in. If not, they've entered the password in wrong. If you're still confused about this, check out this video by computerphile, great video, and channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Just to be clear, an MD5 hash is 'unique'. It can be only produced by one set of bytes, hence why it can be used in this circumstance

Comment: How would I search to see if username was in the database then too see if the password matched

Comment: Simply an SQL query to get an entry where Username=UsersInput, if it returns something then he has a username stored in there. Once you've done that, get the entry and get the password from it. Put basically, `"GET account WHERE username='" + Username + "'"`